# How do I get yarn 2 to work in my project?

Tags: yarnpkg, yarnpkg-v2

I `cd` into my project and run `yarn set version berry`. It creates the `.yarnrc.yml` with the `yarnPath` variable. However, if I do run `yarn` inside the dir it still defaults to the old Yarn. I made a Makefile with commands like `./.yarn/releases/yarn-berry.cjs` + `install` or `start` to get Yarn 2 to work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have `.yarnrc` or `.yarnrc.yml` file in your home directory or in some of the parent folders Yarn 1 finds it and Yarn 2.x never gains control, search for it and remove.

Comment: Any idea where these parent folders could be on a linux/mac?

Comment: If your project is inside `/home/user/foo/bar/project` for example, the parent folders are:
`/home/user/foo/bar`
`/home/user/foo`
`/home/user`